# How to implement Google RecaptchaV2 in Nuxt 3 App

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm actually trying to implement Google reCaptcha in Nuxt App and I'm currently using `"nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.11"`. I try to add this with nuxt2 or vue3 reCaptcha lib but unfortunately, I ended up with some error.

Anyone knows how I implement Google reCaptcha V2 in nuxt 3 App.

Here's my current implementation.

```html
<template>
  <form
    action="?"
    class="mt-8"
    method="POST"
  >
    <div id="g-recaptcha"></div>
  </form>
</template>
```

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
useHead({
    title: 'Contact',
    titleTemplate: 'Gears - %s',
    viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1',
    charset: 'utf-8',
    meta: [
        {name: 'description', content: 'Let’s discuss your work together.'}
    ],
    // Here I Inject reCaptcha script using `useHead()` composable
    script: [
        {
            hid: 'recaptcha',
            src: 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?trustedtypes=true?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit',
            defer: true
        }
    ]
})

const isRecaptchaChecked = ref(false)
const form = reactive({
   token: ''
})

function recaptchaCallback(token) {
    isRecaptchaChecked.value = grecaptcha && grecaptcha.getResponse().length !== 0;
    if (isRecaptchaChecked.value) {
        form.token = token
    }
}

onMounted(async () => {
    await grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
        'sitekey': runtimeConfig.siteKey,
        'callback': recaptchaCallback
    });
})
</script>
```

**Problem #1 with this implementation**

This implementation works fine but It's gave error `ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined` on initial load and if we reload the page the recaptcha works fine and even generate token

**Problem #2 with this implementation**

As I said this It's gave error `ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined` on initial load and when we reload the page this works fine. Now heading to problem 2, the other problem I face is after getting success recaptcha response If we change the page for example we want to go from `/contact` to `/home` the route change on browser URL bar but page is not changed.

Here's the live [Website URL](https://code-creatives.com/)
**Important Note**
Before navigating to contact page please open devtool console and read my two problem and apply them you will understand better about my problem.

Thanks in advance.

**ANNOUNCEMENT**

*I just found a way to implement reCAPTCHA v2 in nuxt3 but before that I want to tell the `@nuxtjs/recapthca` is not compatible with Nuxt3 and when `@nuxtjs/recaptcha` is support Nuxt3 then use `@nuxt-recaptcha` package instead of this solution.*

Here's the [Solution](https://github.com/nuxt-community/recaptcha-module/issues/115#issuecomment-1299982257).

Comment: Maybe set a "onLoad" on the script ?